# jquery text() not comparing to string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript to hide some list Items based on the user role.

I am getting the role from a list item's `text()`. When I am comparing the `$("#activeUser").text()` value against a string, it is not working.

HTML Block that I am using in my javascript to get the text() value of a list item.

```
<ul class="pull-right breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>  <span class="divider">/</span> </li>
    <li id="activeUser" class="active"> <?php echo ucfirst($_SESSION['sewafs_user_role']);  ?> </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testRole = $("#activeUser").text();

    //This block of code works
    role = 'Guest';
    if (role == 'Guest') {
        alert("Inside if");
        $("#request_history_li").hide();
        $("#assign_role_li").hide();
        $("#volunteer_li").hide();
        $("#profile_li").show();
        $("#change_password_li").show();

    }

    //This doesn't work why?
    if (testRole == 'Guest') {
        alert("Inside if");
        $("#request_history_li").hide();
        $("#assign_role_li").hide();
        $("#volunteer_li").hide();
        $("#profile_li").show();
        $("#change_password_li").show();

    }

});
```

But if I see the value of the var testRole using alert it prints Guest.

I tried converting the testRole value into string using testRole.toString() / string(testRole) method, but nothing helped.

Please let me know, where I am going wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem seems to be extra white-spaces in the value that you receive from `$("#activeUser").text()`

**Solution**:
You must trim the value and then use it for comparison as:

```
var testRole = $("#activeUser").text().trim();
```

OR

```
var testRole = $.trim($("#activeUser").text());
```

OR

```
var testRole = $("#activeUser").text();
testRole = $.trim(testRole);
```

Any of the above will work.

*More info on jQuery trim at [this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).*

**Whitespace test:**
If you want to test if you are getting extra white spaces, then try below javascript code:

```
alert("-" + $("#activeUser").text() + "-");
```

If you get "" then you dont have whitespaces in your received value.
But if  you get spaces after `<` or before `>`, then these are white spaces, that are spoiling your party.

Comment: Thank you so much. When I got this problem, I thought the white space may be the problem, but trim() dint strike to me. Thank you for the extra tips.

Answer (score 3):

Try trimming the string, with `$.trim($("#activeUser").text());`
There seem to be whitespaces in your element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trim white spaces at start and end of the string:

```
var testRole = $("#activeUser").text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
```

You can see why here: http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZR/1/

Comment: Thanks for referring "http://jsfiddle.net/AfUZR/1/".I think it will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxjVa/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var testRole = $("#activeUser").text().trim();    
        //This doesn't work why?
        if (testRole == "Guest") {
            alert("Inside if");
            $("#request_history_li").hide();
            $("#assign_role_li").hide();
            $("#volunteer_li").hide();
            $("#profile_li").show();
            $("#change_password_li").show();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Man, first what do you must do it, it's write correct selector.

```
$("#request_history_li").hide();
$("#assign_role_li").hide();
```

you can write

```
$("#request_history_li, #assign_role_li").hide();
```

or you can add the same classes of these Elements, that is correct

```
<ul>
    <li class="same_class 1"></li>
    <li class="same_class 2"></li>
</ul>
```

and

```
$(".same_class").hide();
```

ok? next:

As concerns your problem, js loaded earlier than you determine the role of, use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ......
});
```